# How to add(concatenate) variables inside batch processing in mule 4?

Tags: mule, batch-processing, mule4

I am processing records from one DB to another DB. The batch job is being called multiple times in a single request(triggering the process API URL only one time).
How can I add the total records processed(given by the payload at the on-complete phase) for one complete request?

For eg, I ran the process, and three times the batch job executed. So I want to have the sum of all the records in all the 3 batch jobs.

Comment: How are you executing the batch 3 times? I mean are you executing them sequentially? Or in parallel? If parallel, are you using "Asynch" or for-each-parallel?

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible because of how the Batch scope works:

> In the On Complete phase, none of these variables (not even the
> original ones) are visible. Only the final result is available in this
> phase. Moreover, since the Batch Job Instance executes asynchronously
> from the rest of the flow, no variable set in either a Batch Step or
> the On Complete phase will be visible outside the Batch Scope.

source: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/batch-processing-concept#variable-propagation

What you could do is to store the results in a persistent repository, for example in you database.